# Design regex expression for this html

Tags: html, regex, string, vbscript, html-parsing

In this html line:

```
<b>Cash Out: </b> 2.46x </p> <p> <b>Played: </b>Sat Ene 12 2015 00:20:13
```

How I could match the `2.46x` value?

This is the expression that I've tried to design:

```
"(cash.+out.+\s+)([\d\.]+[^\s])"
```

PS: I know that RegEx motor was not designed to parse Html, but anyways it can be done so please avoid that kind of comments since also I'm using a limited language for this task, **VisualBasicScript**.

Comment: Is there more HTML surrounding the value you are looking for?  That line alone is malformed HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches `<b>Cash Out: </b> 2.46x </p> <p> <b>Played: </b>Sat Ene 12 2015`, right? I'd suggest narrowing it down to after the closing tag + space.

Try this:
`cash.+out.+\s+<\/\w+>\s+([\d\.]+x)`

The value you are looking for will be in the first submatch.